# PHP regex patterns

Tags: php, regex, search, preg-match

I want to know how regex patterns are written. Where is their base and what do I need to know in order to write patterns. I have absolutely no idea on how to write my own patterns and I am quite in a need of finding a particular match in some of my code.

Is this some math based subject? Give me all possible information about patterns please :)

Comment: Great resource: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ (second hit on [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=regular+expressions), right after the Wikipedia entry)

Comment: +1 for the question. Finally somebody is asking where to start! @Felix Kling: Yeah that site is worth the visit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say you need to read the [**PCRE Patterns**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) section of the manual -- and, more specificaly, the [**Pattern Syntax**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) sub-section ;-)

Pretty much everything about PCRE is in there<sup>1</sup>.

Considering that PCRE are, afterall, *Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions*, you might also want to read some Perl-related documentation ; for exemple : [**perlre**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>Well, once again, the PHP manual is so great, it wasn't possible to not link to it...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Pascal Martin already pointed to some useful online resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967094/php-regex-patterns/6967103#6967103). If you're looking for a book, I can suggest [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570).